# How to make a user reinput a value until it is valid

Tags: java, validation, return, java.util.scanner

I've recently started learning Java after spending much time in web design, but while I was trying to create a simple guessing game program I ran into an issue.

```
        final int MAX = 15;
    int answer, guess;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    Random generator = new Random();
    answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;

    System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + MAX + ". Guess what is it: ");

    guess = scan.nextInt();

    if (guess > MAX)
        System.out.println("Please choose a number between 1 and 15.");
    if (guess == answer)
        System.out.println("You got it! Good guessing!");
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This isn't correct, sorry!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
```

I wish to have it so where if a user inputs a value greater than 15 it sends them back to re-enter a valid number between 1 and 15.

On the first if I'm aware it's un-completed as this is where I was planning on adding this feature.

Comment: Have a look at [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), in particular the sections of `for-loop`, `while-loop` and `do-while-loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by having a look at [Control Flow Statements‌​](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), in particular the sections of `for-loop`, `while-loop` and `do-while-loop`

Basically, you need some kind of loop which will continue to repeat until some exit condition is meet (that values for within your specified range)

Something like...

```
do {

    System.out.print("Please choose a number between 1 and " + max + ":");
    guess = scan.nextInt();

} while (guess < 1 || guess > 15);
```

Which will basically continue to prompt the user until they enter a value between 1 and 15 inclusively.

As a runnable example...

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int max = 15;

        int guess = 0;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int answer = generator.nextInt(max) + 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + max + ". Guess what is it\n");
        do {

            do {

                System.out.print("Please choose a number between 1 and " + max + ":");
                guess = scan.nextInt();

            } while (guess < 1 || guess > 15);

            if (guess < answer) {
                System.out.println("Good guess, but mine is higher");
            } else if (guess > answer) {
                System.out.println("Good guess, but mine is low");
            }

        } while (guess != answer);

        System.out.println("Good guess, that's right!");

    }

}
```

**Updated**

Strictly speaking, you don't need the inner loop (in this case), but it does demonstrate how you might be able to re-prompt the user for a single given value.

Another approach might be to use the `if-else` block instead checking the result of the input more directly.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int max = 15;

        int guess = 0;
        Random generator = new Random();
        int answer = generator.nextInt(max) + 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + max + ". Guess what is it\n");
        do {

            System.out.print("Please choose a number between 1 and " + max + ":");
            guess = scan.nextInt();

            if (guess < 1 || guess > 15) {
                System.out.println("You did't enter a valid number, please try again");
            } else if (guess < answer) {
                System.out.println("Good guess, but mine is higher");
            } else if (guess > answer) {
                System.out.println("Good guess, but mine is low");
            }

        } while (guess != answer);

        System.out.println("Good guess, that's right!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to change 
                do {

                System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 and " + max + ":");
                guess = scan.nextInt();

            } while (guess < 1 || guess > 15);

to have just a } while (guess < 1 || guess > 15);
and have it print something seperate only in that case?

For example, if I enter a number within 1 and 15 it goes straight to 'Good guess, but...' but if you DONT enter a number between 1 and 15, it gives an error like "You didn't enter a valid number! Please try again." ?

Comment: The short answer is, yes.  You don't strictly need the inner loop and you could use the `if` statement to determine how to react

Comment: Alright, I think I'm going to try and learn more about while & do before I do much else with this. Better to understand what I'm doing!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use recursion like:

```
/**
         * main business process
         * @param MAX the max number
         * 
         * */
        public static void guess(int MAX) {
            int answer, guess;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
            Random generator = new Random();
            answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + 1;

            guess = scan.nextInt();

            if (guess > MAX || guess < 1) {
                System.out.println("Please choose a number between 1 and 15."); 
                //recursion
                guess(MAX);
            } else if (guess == answer) {
                System.out.println("You got it! Good guessing!");
            } else  {
                System.out.println("This isn't correct, sorry!");
                System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
            }
        }

        /**
         * guessNumber method
         * 
         * */
        public static void guessNumber() {
            final int MAX = 15;
            System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + MAX + ". Guess what is it: ");
            guess(MAX);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            guessNumber();
        }
```

Hope this help!